# Workbooks.Add with Workbook in Class

Tags: excel, vba, class, addition

### 1.Intro

This is my first VBA project and my first post. So please forgive me, if …
It tried everything I could find on the web and I could think of for some days now and finally gave up.
I did several class implementations in the way I understood the web recommendations. Unfortunately this one (but the others) does not work. If I give up the data encapsulation using PRIVATE it would work, but seems to be not clean programming.
I copied the essential part of the code below. This should be enough to reproduce the error (91).
I hope that someone knows some magic characters. I guess it is not much.

Thanks in advance,
Mounty

### 2. Infrastructure

PC: Win7Enterprise-64 SP1, Excel 365 ProPlus-32 (1808)

### 3. Code

Class Module

```
Option Explicit
Private resWrkBook As Workbook         'resultXLS - Result workbook

‘Properties
Public Property Let resultXLS(ByVal resultXLS As Workbook)    'Write value to class variable
    Set resWrkBook = resultXLS                                               'Assign value to property
End Property

Public Property Get resultXLS() As Workbook     'Read value from class variable
    Set resultXLS = resWrkBook                  'Return value from property
End Property
```

Programming Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub main()
    Dim wbs As XlsClass_Module         'declaration

    ‘Short (version S)
    Set wbs.resultXLS = Workbooks.Add    '=> Error 91

    ‘Long (version L, alternative)
    Dim wrk As Workbook
    Set wbs = New XlsClass_Module       'instance of Workbook Class
    Set wrk = Workbooks.Add
    Set wbs.resultXLS = wrk                 '=> Error 91
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the line that says `Public Property Let resultXLS(ByVal resultXLS As Workbook)` to `Public Property Set resultXLS(ByVal resultXLS As Workbook)` and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve it. I used Let and Get so far for encapsulation of all class members (as i learned it from web) and it works.
I just tested your approach. The result (error 91) is unfortunately the same as before.

Comment: Oops... change it to `Public Property Set resultXLS(ByRef resultXLS As Workbook)`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best but still get the same error.
What I saw in my investigations is that there must be a problem in asign the new workbook to the class variable. But I had no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the class module that works and the main code that works. Please see the following code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private resWrkBook As Workbook         'resultXLS - Result workbook

    'Properties
    Public Property Set resultXLS(ByVal resultXLS As Workbook)   'Write value to class variable
        Set resWrkBook = resultXLS                                               'Assign value to property
    End Property

    Public Property Get resultXLS() As Workbook     'Read value from class variable
        Set resultXLS = resWrkBook                  'Return value from property
    End Property
```

And now, the calling code which needs to change (notice the NEW keyword):

```
    Public Sub main()
        Dim wbs As XlsClass_Module          'declaration

        Set wbs = New XlsClass_Module

        'Short (version S)
        Set wbs.resultXLS = Workbooks.Add    '=> Error 91

        'Long (version L, alternative)
        Dim wrk As Workbook
        Set wbs = New XlsClass_Module       'instance of Workbook Class
        Set wrk = Workbooks.Add
        Set wbs.resultXLS = wrk                 '=> Error 91
    End Sub
```

Also, for the variables that you use SET on you need to set them to nothing so that you free up memory:

EX: `set wbs = Nothing`

Comment: I have taken it into my environment, tested it and it works. You saved me so much time!